# Forward cURL-Response-Header in PHP when not using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Tags: php, http, curl

I am proxying the response of a cURL-Request in PHP like this:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);  // makes curl_exec echo the response directly

header_remove();
$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($res) die();
```

My problem is that before cURL outputs the of the response (including the curl response header), the new line is sent that separates the header of my reponse from the body.

Example:

Remote's reponse is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 15:14:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Length: 271
Content-Type: application/json

{"some":"json"}
```

The reponse of my script is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 446
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Length: 271
Content-Type: application/json

{"some":"json"}
```

What I want is to use the remote's response a my own.

Of course I could

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

but I don't want to only be able to proxy something that responds JSON.

Also I could

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

and parse the response's header for the Content-Type but in that case I would not be able to forward large responses that exceed my memory and it would increase the latency of my script a lot because I could not start sending my response before cURL completed fetching the remotes response.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Barmer I got it working like this:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         false);  // IMPORTANT
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
  function($curl, $content)
  {
    if (!headers_sent()) header('Content-Type: '.curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
    echo $content;
    return strlen($content);
  }
);

header_remove();
$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($res) die();
```

Explanation:

First I needed to change CURLOPT_HEADER to false.

Then I needed the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION which is called for every chunk that is echoed by cURL. That is why I only add to the header when they are not sent.
I pumped an ISO of Ubuntu through it an it does not cache the content.

Next I will investigate the chunksize and if I can set it myself or at least how cURL decides the it.

**Edit:** Chunksize in my case is always 16384 bytes.

**Edit:** I can confirm, that a >2GB file downloaded with this method does not differ from the same file downloaded with wget.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` and/or `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I played around with CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION but with no luck. I will investigate CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.

Comment: `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` should solve the problem of having to read the entire response into memory.

Comment: Unfortunately when using CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION it compromises the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option because I have to echo the body myself which I get in the second parameter of my writefunction. Having the content already in a string variable tells me the content is cached even if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set to false.

Comment: Of course you do. But you do it incrementally rather than reading the entire response all at once.

Comment: Barmar! YOU ARE THE MAN!